# Move Image column from OracleDB top SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, linked-server, openquery

I have access to an Oracle database and I need to bring its data into SQL Server. The table has a simple structure and I can't change anything on the Oracle side.

I created a linked server inside SQL Server but I can't select the table because of this error :

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column (compile-time ordinal 1) of object was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH" of 16 at compile time and 0 at run time

[The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column (compile-time ordinal 1) of object was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH" of 16 at compile time and 0 at run time](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a3b7a7f-2906-4088-8eb0-fba11034abad/the-ole-db-provider-quotoraoledboraclequot-for-linked-server-supplied-inconsistent-metadata?forum=databasedesign)

I checked and it seems to be a general problem and Oracle suggested using `OPENQUERY` to get data from these tables.

When I use `OPENQUERY` the `IMAGE` ( 'BFILE' ) column is null but I can see in SQL Developer that it is not null.

When I use SSIS, I get this error:

> ADO NET Source [33]] Error: The error "ORA-00972: identifier is too long occurred while processing "ADO NET Source.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[IMAGE]

Any ideas on how to move a table with an `IMAGE` (BFILE) column from Oracle database to SQL Server?

Comment: What data type is the column in Oracle?  `image` isn't an Oracle data type.  Perhaps that is a user-defined object data type in your Oracle system?  Or perhaps you mean `ORDImage`?  Or is it a `blob`?  Or something else?

Comment: @JustinCave it is BFILE